# Cannot convert multiple Pandas columns from Object to Datetime type in the existing Dataframe (inplace update)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have a Pandas dataframe with over ten columns, and most of these columns are Pandas 'object' type.

I need to convert three of these columns from 'object' to 'datetime' type and write back to the existing dataframe columns (to perform '***inplace update***').

I am using the following code as the starting point for just one column and plan to expand on it for the other two columns, but it is not working.

The '**bigframe**' dataframe has many duplicate rows. I am dropping duplicate rows based on '**incidentId**' and assigning unique rows to '**alerts**' below.

```
alerts = bigframe.drop_duplicates(subset=['incidentId'])
alerts['firstEventTime'] = pd.to_datetime(alerts['firstEventTime'])
```

The content of **alerts['firstEventTime']** is similar to '**2021-01-27 22:34:05.991031+00:00**'

I am getting the following warning, but the code's execution completes without an error.

**"*A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead*"**

When I type '**a*lerts.dtypes***', I still see this column is listed as '***object***' type. So, I am assuming that the operations is not written back to the original dataframe for some reason.

I searched the internet, and the code listed above was supposed to work, but it doesn't. So I must be doing something wrong, but I cannot find it. Would you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add an example of the content of `alerts['firstEventTime']`? Also, is `alerts` a slice from another df?

Comment: @MrFuppes - Yes, 'alerts' is a slice from another larger dataframe that has duplicate rows. 'alerts' drops the duplicates. The content of `alerts['firstEventTime']` is `2021-01-27 22:34:05.991031+00:00`

Comment: ok and the UTC offset `+00:00` is it *always* zero hours or maybe sometimes e.g. `+01:00`?

Comment: @MrFuppes - Thank you for suggesting a potential issue with the UTC offset values. I reviewed the `content of alerts['firstEventTime']`. The majority of rows have UTC offset as +00:00. However, there are some discrepancies. Some of the rows have values similar to `2022-01-18 20:34:52`.

Comment: @MrFuppes - Would that discrepancy prevent the conversion of the `alerts['firstEventTime']` column type from object to datetime? How can I fix it?

Comment: yes, pandas datetime dtype cannot handle mixed UTC offsets. You can `pd.to_datetime(alerts['firstEventTime'], utc=True)` to convert all date/times to UTC and get a datetime64[ns] dtype column. If you need time to be in a specific time zone, use `.dt.tz_convert("your-tz-name")` on the column to convert afterwards.

Comment: regarding the "set on a copy of a slice" warning, you can use `.copy()` for example to make a new df explicitly (e.g. like  `new_df = old_df[list_of_columns_names].copy()`).

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is very helpful. Is there a way to convert your comments above as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's two unrelated issues here;

#1 [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) returns a slice of the existing df, not a new df. You can avoid the warning by [copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)ing the result to a new df explicitly.

#2 pandas datetime dtype cannot handle mixed UTC offsets within one Series. It falls back to using Python's datetime in such cases, i.e. the elements are of type datetime.datetime which is displayed as 'object'. You can handle this by converting to UTC with keyword `utc=True`.

EX:

```
bigframe = pd.DataFrame({'incidentId': [1,1,2],
                         'firstEventTime': ['2021-01-27 22:34:05.991031+00:00',
                                            '2021-01-27 22:34:05.991031+00:00', 
                                            '2022-01-18 20:34:52']})

# avoid the warning by explicitly calling .copy():
alerts = bigframe.drop_duplicates(subset=['incidentId']).copy()

# now convert to datetime in UTC, to get a datetime64[ns] dtyped Series:
alerts['firstEventTime'] = pd.to_datetime(alerts['firstEventTime'], utc=True)

alerts['firstEventTime']
# 0   2021-01-27 22:34:05.991031+00:00
# 2          2022-01-18 20:34:52+00:00
# Name: firstEventTime, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

Note that pandas will assume the input is UTC if no UTC offset is specified.